# Pause a javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm looking for a chrome feature similar to debugger/breakpoint that lets me pause a script.

Why. I like to test some css in chrome-inspector. Since it's a loading spinner it will only be visible for some milliseconds. That time is to short to play with css ;)

Why not breakpoint...
Because chrome covers the entire page with a black layer so I cannot right-click and inspect a DOM-element as I like.

So is it possible to get rid of the black layer chrome has in debegger mode? or can I simply pause a script, play around with the css and the play it again.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What black layer? I can inspect the DOM fine when on a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript, you can simply write:

```
console.log(element);
debugger;
```

When the Chrome developer tools console is open, this line will pause your script without placing a breakpoint manually. `console.log(element);` will let you access the element you wish to debug or modify via the console.

After the script stops, you can use the DOM explorer, select your element, and in the DOM properties window, under "Styles", change its `display` property to `none` to make it disappear.

[image]

Comment: That's a good tip... but is it only me thinking this is a bit too much hassle to find the element with javascript and then console.log it + setting a break point and then remove the black layer with the inspector. 

I think I found a easer solution to my own question. Simply use the select-element tool in chrome rather than right click. It temporary removes the black-layer until the element is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ok answer to my own question. Simply use the select-element tool in chrome rather than right click.

[image: left icon]

*Icon to the left*

It temporary removes the black-layer until the element is selected. But if you want to see the correct colors without the black layer covering it you need to display:none it in the inspector. Also if you want to work on hovers or other similar stats the black layer will prevent hovers and such.